# How to aggregate two messages in single route?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have one route that collects headers and sends a request to another queue from which I wait for an answer (I only need the response body). The problem is that both the headers and the answer I want to receive in one message in one route, but now I get two messages in one route (I need to aggregate the response body and headers). 
how to do it?

```
from("jms:queue:aaa")
    .log("incoming message")
    .process(exchange -> {
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("c", c);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("d", d);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("a", a);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("b", b);
        exchange.getIn().setBody("2+3");
    })
    .removeHeaders("*", "a", "b", "c", "d")
    .setHeader("JMSReplyTo", simple("bbb"))
        //send request
    .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "jms:ccc?preserveMessageQos=true&includeSentJMSMessageID=true")
        //trying to send headers from this route to bbb
    .to(ExchangePattern.InOut, "jms:bbb")
.end();
from("jms:bbb")
    .log("${headers}\n${}body")
.end();
```

from("jms:bbb") 
this is the route in which I want to combine the results from .
`.to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "jms:ccc?preserveMessageQos=true& includeSentJMSMessageID=true")` .
and .
`.to (ExchangePattern.InOut, "jms: bbb")`

UPD:

```
public class AggregationStrategyImpl implements AggregationStrategy {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AggregationStrategyImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        if(newExchange == null)
            newExchange = oldExchange;
        String a = oldExchange.getIn().getHeader("a", String.class);
        String b = oldExchange.getIn().getHeader("b", String.class);
        String c = oldExchange.getIn().getHeader("c", String.class);
        String d = oldExchange.getIn().getHeader("d", String.class);
        newExchange.getIn().setHeader("a", a);
        newExchange.getIn().setHeader("b", b);
        newExchange.getIn().setHeader("c", c);
        newExchange.getIn().setHeader("d", d);

        return newExchange;
    }
}
```

```
 .setHeader("JMSReplyTo", simple("bbb"))
                    .multicast(aggregationStrategy)
                    .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "jms:ccc?preserveMessageQos=true&includeSentJMSMessageID=true")
                    .to(ExchangePattern.OutOnly, "jms:bbb")
```

Comment: Will there always be two messages, and they need to be grouped together? What shows that they belong together? Is there some type of shared key/id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/aggregator2.html).
It looks like your first `if` statement doesn't work:

```
if(newExchange == null) 
  newExchange = oldExchange;
```

This way the newly incoming exchange object will always stay null.
Instead, it should be the other way, because you want to keep `oldExchange`, when a `newExchange` comes in:

```
if (oldExchange == null) {
    //...
    return newExchange;
} else {
    //...
    return oldExchange;
}
```

The problem seems to be that you are waiting for `newExchange` to be null, but there **always** is a `newExchange`, if aggregate is called. The very first exchange object to come is a `newExchange`, too. Instead the first call of aggregate does not have an `oldExchange`!

Answer (score 0):

````
                .log("incoming message")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("c", c);
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("d", d);
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("a", a);
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("b", b);
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("2+3");
                })
                .removeHeaders("*", "a", "b", "c", "d")
                .setHeader("JMSReplyTo", simple("bbb"))
                //send request
                .multicast(aggregateStratergeyBean)
                .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "jms:ccc?preserveMessageQos=true&includeSentJMSMessageID=true")
                //trying to send headers from this route to bbb
                .to(ExchangePattern.InOut, "jms:bbb")
                .end();
        from("jms:bbb")
                .log("${headers}\n${}body")
                .end();```

aggregateStratergeyBean should implements AggregationStrategy. 

Also you can use many options like below

.parallelProcessing(true)   // Parallel process both routes

.parallelAggregate()  // Aggregate parallel , you need to handle thread safety

.streaming(). // Process response as and when it get the response not in the order it invoked.
````

Comment: I'm implements AggregationStrategy, but it's does't work. what am I doing wrong? see UPD

Comment: Yes you implemented AggregationStrategy, but you intermingled `oldExchange` and `newExchange`. See my answer above.